# XCUIElement exists, but is not hittable

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

In my UI tests, I create a `UIView` programmatically using (shortened)

```
let topMarker = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init())
…
topMarker.accessibilityIdentifier = kTopMarker
```

The `topMarker` view is in a custom table view cell.
In my UI tests, I use

```
let new1stCell = app.cells.element(boundBy: 0)
let topMarker = new1stCell.otherElements[kTopMarker]
let topMarkerExists = topMarker.waitForExistence(timeout: 15)
XCTAssertTrue(topMarkerExists, "Top marker does not exist")
XCTAssertTrue(topMarker.isHittable, "Top marker is not hittable")
```

When I set a Test Failure breakpoint, the test stops at the last line, i.e. `topMarker` exists, but is not hittable.
On the other hand, I can see the view in the snapshot, i.e. it exists and is visible.
This is stange, because the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500561-ishittable) say:

*isHittable returns true if the element exists and can be clicked, tapped, or pressed at its current location. It returns false if the element does not exist, is offscreen, or is covered by another element.*

I thought, maybe it is visible, but cannot be clicked, tapped, or pressed, because `userInteractionEnable` is not `true`, but even if I set this property to `true`, the view does not become hittable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem solved:
**An XCUIElement is only hittable, if its `isAccessibilityElement` property is set to true.**
The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615141-isaccessibilityelement) to property `isAccessibilityElement` say

*The default value for this property is false unless the receiver is a standard UIKit control, in which case the value is true.

Assistive applications can get information only about objects that are represented by accessibility elements. Therefore, if you implement a custom control or view that should be accessible to users with disabilities, set this property to true.*

My `UIView` that I instantiated programmatically is **not** a standard UIKit control. As soon as I added

```
topMarker.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

the test

```
XCTAssertTrue(topMarker.isHittable, "Top marker is not hittable")
```

succeeded.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in SwiftUI?

Comment: Apples framework is messed up. This is a broken API. Turning on `isAccessibilityElement ` will tell the accessibility engine that this item has a label and value that can be read. That is not the same thing as being hittable. This is really bad implementation by Apple.