# SwiftUI: Custom view is un-hittable in XCTest

Tags: swiftui, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

During Xcode UI test, I found my custom view's (MenuViewButton) is un-hittable in a test, I could found it but cannot touch it. In debug , when I po `isHittable` in console, it returns false. However I'm not sure if this is the correct behavior.

Per this thread [XCUIElement exists, but is not hittable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849308/10158398) said, `isHittable` is default false for custom view element, and default true for UIKit standard view. But I don't know if it is the same behavior in SwiftUI.

Since the way `someView.isAccessibilityElement = true`  is not possible in SwiftUI. My question is how could I let my custom view became hittable? Then it could be tapped in a test.

```
    private var aView: some View {
        MenuViewButton(
            image: Image("an image name"),
            text: Text("a string")
        )
        .accessibility(identifier: "xxx name")
    }
```

I also use force tap with coordinate in case tap() is not working, but to give a offset of `normalizedOffset` didn't fix the problem in all places, it means some un-hittable element could be tapped, that is great but some others still not.

So may I know where `normalizedOffset` is start, from the middle of frame to give the offset or the top left?

```
    func forceTapElement(timeout: TimeInterval) {
        if !self.waitForExistence(timeout: timeout) {
            return
        }
        
        if self.isHittable {
            self.tap()
        } else {
            let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.0))
            coordinate.tap()
        }
    }
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714744/xcuitest-failed-to-synthesize-event-failed-to-compute-hit-point-for-button/62717015#62717015 for more details

Answer (score 0):

1. Add https://github.com/devexperts/screenobject as a dependency
2. Use `.tapUnhittable()` instead of `.tap()` for this particular view. It gets the coordinates and taps using them

Comment: Yeah, I used coordinate within a custom touch function. Please see my update in OP.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and am looking for answers. What has worked for me was to use:
`let coordinate = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))`

Still this seems like workaround for a real problem. One other strange thing is that i do not have this problem on iOS15.0 simulator, only for later versions. Currently trying with iOS15.2

One more thing I've tried is to add
`.accessibilityElement(children: .combine)`
and specificly telling it's a button with
`.accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)`
But this doesn't solve the problem.

Seems that isAccessibilityElement would be an answer here, but SwiftUI doesn't seem to have such.